# Chrome infinite loop trying to update - Galaxy Tab S

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android

what's up?

So I recently bought a brand new Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4". Bought it online, waited a few days, got my new tablet through mail! \o/ YEY! Nice, as a regular-heavy-user, the first thing I was to check if it had an update to the lollipop, which it did! \o/ YEY again! Nice, so far, so good.

After the lollipop update it started to update a whole bunch of apps, which is fine. The thing is, the Google Chrome (yeap, the browser) started to try to update... and try... and try... and nothing happened since. It's been like a month or so and througout day and night Chrome is trying to begin the download to update, but it can't. That green running line in the bottom keeps moving forever and nothing ever happens.

Does someone know how can I force stop it from trying to update?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Typical solution for something like this:

1. Open *Play Store*
2. Swipe in from the left side and tap *My apps*
3. You'll see a list of apps installed, and at the top are apps that need updates, or are in the process of updating.
4. Find Chrome in the top section, tap on it, and tap the X on the right side of the status. This will stop the current download.
5. Head into your main system settings, *Apps*, and locate Chrome. It may be in the *Downloaded* section, or the *All* section, depending on whether it managed to download ANY updates at any point.
6. Tap on it, and then tap the *UNINSTALL UPDATES* button. If button doesn't exist, or is ghosted, continue to step 7.
7. Tap the *CLEAR DATA* and *CLEAR CACHE* buttons as well.
8. Restart your phone to play it safe.
9. Reopen *Play Store* and search for *Chrome* and attempt to manually force an update.
10. Come back here and comment about what happened.